# Share strategy matrix between workflows in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

I have a multi-module gradle project where each sub-module is an independent project.
I have multiple CI pipelines that are running on each CI pipeline in parallel (e.g. build, linters, etc.) whenever a change is introduced in the submodule.

However, at this point, I need to copy and paste the names of the modules (which are already 22 and expected to grow dramatically in the future).

Is there a possibility of extracting the strategy matrix into a shared file that I can include in multiple pipelines? I've seen some questions about the topic on StackOverflow but none of them helping my situation.

You can see an example of one of the pipelines here:

```yaml
name: ci

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [ opened, synchronize, reopened, ready_for_review ]

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        design-pattern: [
          "abstract-factory",
          "adapter",
          "bridge",
          "builder",
          "chain-of-responsibility",
          "command",
          "composite",
          "decorator",
          "facade",
          "factory-method",
          "flyweight",
          "iterator",
          "mediator",
          "observer",
          "prototype",
          "proxy",
          "singleton",
          "state",
          "static-factory-method",
          "strategy",
          "template-method",
          "visitor",
        ]
    steps:

      - name: Git Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Install Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: 17
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Check for Changes
        uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2.11.1
        id: changes
        with:
          filters: |
            source_code:
              - '.github/workflows/**'
              - '${{ matrix.design-pattern }}/src/**'
              - '${{ matrix.design-pattern }}/build.gradle.kts'
              - 'build.gradle.kts'
              - 'gradle/libs.versions.toml'
              - 'settings.gradle.kts'
              - 'gradle.properties'
            docs:
              - '${{ matrix.design-pattern }}/README.md'
              - README.md

      - name: Gradle Build
        if: steps.changes.outputs.source_code == 'true'
        id: tests
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: ./gradlew ${{ matrix.design-pattern }}:spotlessCheck ${{ matrix.design-pattern }}:build

  ci-check:
    if: always()
    needs:
      - ci
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Decide whether all CI jobs are succeeded or failed
        uses: re-actors/alls-green@release/v1
        with:
          jobs: ${{ toJSON(needs) }}
```

Comment: The idea to use a matrix strategy for this issue is good, however I would use it only after identifying which folders have been updated, in another job. I've done something similar [in this workflow](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/poc-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/63-matrix-folder.yml) if you want to have a look.

Comment: That is not a bad idea, however I see 2 issues here: 1st i still need to duplicate the list, and 2nd (also exist in the original) when introducing a new module it would re-run all submodules as the workflow have to change, that's why I wanted to extract it away

Comment: Is it a problem to rerun the workflow in that case? Has you will check which folders have been updated before executing each ci operation, the workflow would only run for the new introduced module, right? Regarding the duplication, I understand it would only exists in the `setup` job that would check the folders, and this job will need to be updated anyway when adding new modules each time to the `dorny/paths-filter`, for them to be checked alongside the others. The whole workflow could then be run on any event.